# How can i make one line of code work after the previous one finished?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change the state of the component only after a function I call has finished.
The function contains a interval that ends after some time.
i have tried using busy-wait, using await but it doesn't seem to work for me.

This is the way I initialize the state

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            array: [],
            status: false
        }
    }
```

This is the function that i try to make wait for one of lines to finish.

```
bubble_sort_visualize(){
        if(this.state.status === false){
            this.setState({status: true});
            const arr = this.state.array.slice();
            const animations = this.bubble_sort_and_push([], arr);
            this.animate(animations);
            // need to make it work after animate finishes
            this.setState({status: false});
        }
    }
```

This is the function that i want to finish before the other line starts.

```
animate(animations){    
        const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'bisque', '#80ff80'];
        const bars = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
        let i = 0;
        const intervalHander = function(){
            const animation = animations[i];
            const bar1 = bars[animation[0]];
            const bar2 = bars[animation[1]];
            const color = colors[animation[2]];
            changeColor(bar1, bar2, color);
            i++;
            if(i === animations.length){
                window.clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
        const interval = window.setInterval(intervalHander,0.5);
    }
```

so basically I'm trying to change the state in the ***bubble_sort_visualize*** method after the ***animate*** method has executed the clearInterval operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want setState to trigger after all animation have finished withih animate function which triggers execution in a setInterval, you would need to convert animate to return a promise like

```
animate(animations){  
   return new Promise(res => {
        const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'bisque', '#80ff80'];
        const bars = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
        let i = 0;
        const intervalHander = function(){
            const animation = animations[i];
            const bar1 = bars[animation[0]];
            const bar2 = bars[animation[1]];
            const color = colors[animation[2]];
            changeColor(bar1, bar2, color);
            i++;
            if(i === animations.length){
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                res();
            }
        }
        const interval = window.setInterval(intervalHander,0.5);
   })  
}
```

and use it like

```
async bubble_sort_visualize(){
    if(this.state.status === false){
        this.setState({status: true});
        const arr = this.state.array.slice();
        const animations = this.bubble_sort_and_push([], arr);
        await this.animate(animations);
        this.setState({status: false});
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to have helped

Answer (score 0):

This is what I will do. I will call the function after the animation is finish.

Something like this:

```
animate(animations){    
        const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'bisque', '#80ff80'];
        const bars = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
        let i = 0;
        const intervalHander = function(){
            const animation = animations[i];
            const bar1 = bars[animation[0]];
            const bar2 = bars[animation[1]];
            const color = colors[animation[2]];
            changeColor(bar1, bar2, color);
            i++;
            if(i === animations.length){
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                this.bubble_sort_visualize()
            }
        }
        const interval = window.setInterval(intervalHander,0.5);
    }
```

I assume that the animation is finish when `i === animations.length`

Comment: I'm not sure it will work because I think the function intervalHander doesn't recognize 'this'. I have tried it and as i thought, it threw an error about 'this'

Comment: Hey, if this is your only concern, you can bind the correct "this" context to your function by calling it this way: `const interval = window.setInterval(intervalHander.bind(this),0.5);`